# How to open in new tab and switch to that tab with Cypres?

Tags: typescript, tabs, window, cypress

Technologies: Cypress, Typescript

I am trying to get link from mail and open in new tab, using this code

```
let newUrl = '';
cy.window().then((win) => {
  cy.stub(win, 'open').as('windowOpen').callsFake(url => {
    newUrl = url;
  });
})
getIframeBody().find('table#emailContainer tr td a').click();
cy.get('@windowOpen').should('be.called');
```

Unfortunatelly I get error:
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected windowOpen to have been called at least once, but it was never called

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs#Multiple-tabs

Comment: Multiple tabs don't apply here, the `window.open` method is being stubbed.

Answer (score 1):

You are stubbing the wrong window. `cy.window()` gives you the iframe that runs the app, but your app has another iframe that should be the target of your stub.

Something like this, but may fall foul of iframe loading problems

```js
cy.get('iframe#my-iframe')
  .its('0.contentWindow')
  .then((win) => {

    let newUrl = '';
    cy.stub(win, 'open').as('windowOpen').callsFake(url => newUrl = url)

    getIframeBody().find('table#emailContainer tr td a')
      .click()
      .then(() => {
        cy.get('@windowOpen').should('be.calledWith', newUrl)
      })
  })
```